# Beamer,adjust separator in top/bottom lines

Tags: beamer

I would like to adjust the separators (to the left) in the top and bottom lines of beamer slide with Warsaw theme, so that there is more space to the right of separator. Is it possible?

Minimal working example:

```
    \documentclass[slidestop,compress,11pt]{beamer}
    \mode<presentation> {
        \usetheme{Warsaw}
    }
    \title[Test]{Test }
    \begin{document}
    \section{section1}
    \subsection{subsection1}
    \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{subsection2}
    \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile (at least not under pdfLaTeX). Please fix it.

Comment: The should be <presentation>  after \mode, but by some reason it doesn't show up. don't know how to fix it,sorry.

Comment: Removing the `<code>` and `</code>` tags did the trick, i.e., made `<presentation>` show up. :-)

Comment: Can you please clarify what separator you are talking about and where the space shall be increased? Perhaps take a screenshot and mark the area?

Comment: separator between black and blue areas on the very top and very bottom lines (on slide from MWE code). On the top line it splits chapter's and section's names. I don't know how to post screenshots here yet. I will add a couple sections in a minute so that it become more clear.

Comment: I updated MWE. The top separator is between 'section1' and 'subsection1'. I would like to get more space for subsections by shifting separator to the left. There is another one on the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the width of the `beamercolorbox`es is `wd=.5\paperwidth` for both sides. In the following example I shifted them to `.3` and `.7` [the width of the navigation element has to be changed in the same way]

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,11pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
}
\title[Test]{Test}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{section in head/foot}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{.3\paperwidth}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.7\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{.7\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.7\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{section1}
\subsection{subsection1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\subsection{subsection2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thats what I'm trying to do, thank you! This is much more code than I expected, and I don't understand 90% of it. Still fine if it doesn't interfere with the other code I have (still need to verify this). Could you please explain how does the above code works? Where can I find documentation about macros you used here?

Comment: which parameter affects the position of separator?

Comment: There is no parameter for the position, but in each bar are two boxes besides each other and you can manipulate their width by changing the three occurrences of `wd=.3\paperwidth` and the three ones of `wd=.7\paperwidth` [the sum should add to one in order to fill the whole page]. Documentation about the components can be found in the beamer user guide.

Comment: @strider I think I forgot to ping you. So see comment above.